# Can a partial F test test a contrast

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, f-test

Suppose I have a model
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} + \beta_3x_{3i} + \epsilon_i \qquad (1)$$
Now I want to test $$H_0: \beta_2 = \beta_3$$
I know that I can use a Wald-type test for testing the contrast, but I just wonder if I can have a "nested" model
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 (x_{2i} + x_{3i}) + \epsilon_i \qquad (2)$$
and then use the partial F test to test $H_0$?

I also wonder if anyone has a formal proof for the partial F test that I can refer to? Thanks.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for your comment, but I do not mean $\beta_2 = \beta_3 = 0$, but $\beta_2 = \beta_3$ only.

Comment: My apologies, I seem to have linked the wrong page. I was trying to point to a discussion of tests for the general linear hypothesis which includes yours as a special case. (Your partial F test is correct, by the way.)

Comment: @Glen_b No need for apologies, I thank you for actually commenting. But do you know any proof of the test so that I can understand it better? Also, I thought usually general linear hypothesis are tested using a Wald-type test? is an $F$-test applicable though?

Comment: @Glen_b Oh never mind I think I have found the link you mentioned.